# has ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17 been trained on labelled dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

Has the COCO dataset been labeled on this pre-trained model?

I am trying to figure out if the object detection that happens after using this pre-trained model is actually an output of an unlabelled data, or there was some labeling which made the model more efficient.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The COCO dataset wasn't labelled using the pre-trained model. Rather the pre-trained model was trained on COCO annotations.

Comment: @VishnuDasu do you mean by COCO annotations is that the images used in this dataset contain labels (rectangles on objects)? 
That's what I'm trying to figure out!